# Transferring data from one memory location to another in 8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16

The question is:

> Write an assembly language program to move 16 bytes of data starting from the offset 0200H to 0300H in the segment 7000H.

How do I write the program? I mean, how should I take the address? Should I consider the offset address or the base address?

Comment: They give you the segment (base) and offset. From that, you can easily calculate the absolute address. But you don't even need it, because the 8086 uses segment-offset addressing, so they give you all the values you need to plug in. This is a pretty simple exercise, if you understand what segment registers are and are familiar with the string instructions (in particular, `MOVSB`).

Answer (score 4):

> How do I write the program?

You write a loop that successively reads from the source addresses and writes at the destination addresses.

> I mean, how should I take the address?
>   Should I consider the offset address or the base address?

To address memory you need to use both address components.

- You put the given segment value in a segment register. `DS` is the more usual choice:

  ```
  mov     ax, 7000h
  mov     ds, ax
  ```
- You put the provided source offset in an address register like `BX`, `SI`, or `DI`:

  ```
  mov     si, 0200h
  ```
- You put the provided destination offset in a **different** address register:

  ```
  mov     di, 0300h
  ```
- You put the requested number of bytes in one of the remaining general purpose registers, `CX` being the natural choice and indeed the only choice if we want to use the `LOOP` instruction:

  ```
  mov     cx, 16
  ```

---

All the above choices lead to the following loop:

```
Again:
    mov     al, [si]   ;Get 1 byte from the source range
    inc     si         ;Point to the next byte
    mov     [di], al   ;Write 1 byte in the destination range
    inc     di         ;Point to the next byte
    loop    Again      ;Decrement the counter and jump to the label "Again"
                       ; if the counter is not yet exhausted.
```

This is but one solution to your task. Many more exist.
The shortest solution however uses a specialized instruction like `MOVS`. Look it up in your textbook and see what is required to start using it. Happy discovery!

Please note that all the above code does not constitute a complete working program.

Comment: It's a 16-byte copy from even (aligned) addresses.  You'd normally copy at least 2 bytes at a time with `mov ax, [si]` / `mov [di], ax`.

Answer (score -1):

```
section .data
    source_data db 0x55    ; Source data to transfer
    destination_data times 1 db 0   ; Destination data (initialized with zeros)

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    ; Move data from source_data to destination_data
    mov al, [source_data]   ; Load data from source_data into AL register
    mov [destination_data], al   ; Store data from AL register into destination_data

    ; Exit the program
    mov eax, 1     ; Exit syscall number
    xor ebx, ebx   ; Exit status
    int 0x80       ; Call kernel
```

Comment: This answers the title question (for 32-bit Linux instead of 8086), but ignores the question body.  To copy 16 bytes, use `movups xmm0, [src]` / `movups [dst], xmm0`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).